# Creating self signed certificate - ./makecert using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below code for enabling WinRM https listener but while executing the code in Powershell, I am getting the following error:

> .\makecert : The term '.\makecert' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path  was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

I tried to provide the fully qualified path of cert.exe, but that didn't work. After providing the fully qualified path, I started getting the following new error:

> Get-Random : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name
>   'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -ErrorAction
>   -ErrorVariable

**Full code:**

```
function Configure-WinRMHttpsListener
{
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string] $HostName,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string] $port)

# Delete the WinRM Https listener if it is already configured
Delete-WinRMListener

# Create a test certificate
$thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=" + $hostname } | Select-Object -Last 1).Thumbprint
if(-not $thumbprint)
{

    #$serial = Get-Random 
    #"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\makecert.exe" -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -# $serial 

    #$thumbprint=(Get-ChildItem cert:\Localmachine\my | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=" + $hostname } | Select-Object -Last 1).Thumbprint
    #C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makecert -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12


    $serial = Get-Random .\makecert -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -# $serial

    $thumbprint=(Get-ChildItem cert:\Localmachine\my | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=" + $hostname } | Select-Object -Last 1).Thumbprint


    if(-not $thumbprint)
    {
        throw "Failed to create the test certificate."
    }
}    

$response = cmd.exe /c .\winrmconf.cmd $hostname $thumbprint
}
```

Comment: `$serial = Get-Random .\makecert -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -# $serial` how do you expect this to work?

Comment: Why don't you use the native powershell cmdlet for this? New-SelfSignedCertificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$serial = Get-Random .\makecert -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -# $serial
```

Is actually two separate lines of code that seem to have inadvertently got merged on to one (`$serial = get-random` being the first line). They either need to be separated by a semi-colon (after get-random) or put on two separate lines as fllows. You'll also probably need to use the full path to Makecert.exe (or alternatively be running the script from the directory it is in but still referencing it as `.\makecert.exe`):

Correct the above code to this:

```
$serial = Get-Random 
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\makecert.exe" -r -pe -n CN=$hostname -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2022 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -# $serial
```

Comment: For the last line to work you need to put the path in quotes and use the call operator.